# My C++ program in Turbo C++ gets hanged after some time

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, bgi

It is a rather simple snake game. It just gets hanged.
When I try to execute it, it runs for a while and then hangs in some moments.
Please Tell me what to do?
This is turbo C++ version 3.0 and please do not tell me to use new version. And don't call me outdated, I know that.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int x,y,a,b,flag,i,discx,discy,sc,maxx,maxy,same;
short int arr[100][2];
char ch,check;
void shift();
int introscreen();
void condition();
void gameover();
void score();
void randomapple();

int introscreen()
    {
     outtextxy(maxx/2,30,"SNAKE");
     outtextxy((maxx/2)-10,50,"INSTRUCTIONS");
     outtextxy(5,70,"W A S D represent Top Right Bottom Left respectively.");
     outtextxy(5,90,"Press Spacebar to quit any moment");
     outtextxy(5,110,"To play Press Space else anything else");
     char take=getch();
     if(take==' ')
     return 1;
     else
     return 0;
     }
void randomapple()
{same=0;
while(1)
{
 a=random(maxx-5);
 b=random(maxy-5);
 for(i=0;i<flag;i++)
 {if((abs(a-arr[i][0]<=5)&&abs(b-arr[i][1]<=5))||a<=5||b<=5)
  same=1;
 }
 if(same==0) break;
 }
 setcolor(RED);
 outtextxy(a,b,"0");
 setcolor(WHITE);
}
void shift()
    {discx=arr[flag-1][0];
     discy=arr[flag-1][1];
     for(i=flag-1;i>0;i--)
        {
         arr[i][0]=arr[i-1][0];
         arr[i][1]=arr[i-1][1];
         }
     arr[0][0]=x;
     arr[0][1]=y;
     }
void printsnake()
    {
     setcolor(BLACK);
     outtextxy(discx,discy,"X");
     setcolor(GREEN);
     outtextxy(x,y,"X");
     setcolor(RED);
     outtextxy(a,b,"0");
     rectangle(0,0,maxx,maxy);
     delay(5);
    }
void condition()
    {
     switch(ch)
        {
         case'd':x++;
             break;
         case'a':x--;
             break;
         case'w':y--;
             break;
         case's':y++;
             break;
         case' ':exit(1);

        }
     }
    void score()
    {if((abs(x-a)<=5)&&(abs(y-b)<=5))
     {sc++;
     if(flag<500)
     flag=flag+10;
     setcolor(BLACK);
     outtextxy(a,b,"0");
     randomapple();
     }

    if(sc==100)
    {
        clrscr();
        cout<<"You are the champion tonight!!!!";
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    }
void collision()
    {
     if(x<=5||y<=5||maxx-x<=5||maxy-y<=5)
     gameover();
     for(i=1;i<flag;i++)
     {
      if(arr[0][0]==arr[i][0]&&arr[0][1]==arr[i][1])
      gameover();
     }
    }
void gameover()
    {textcolor(BLACK);
     clrscr();
     textcolor(WHITE);
     cout<<"YOU LOSE!\n";
     cout<<"GAME OVER\n";
     cout<<"Final Score = "<<sc;
     getch();
     getch();
     getch();
     getch();
     exit(1);
    }
void main()
    {
     randomize();
     int gdriver = DETECT, gmode, errorcode;
     /* initialize graphics mode */
     initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "");
     maxx=500;
     maxy=400;
     x=maxx/2;
     y=maxy/2;
     ch='d';
     sc=0;
     if(introscreen())
     {
     textcolor(BLACK);
     clrscr();
     rectangle(0,0,maxx,maxy);
     flag=20;
     setcolor(GREEN);
     for(i=19;i>=0;i--)
     {arr[i][0]=x-i;
      arr[i][1]=y-i;
      outtextxy(x-i,y-i,"X");
     }
     setcolor(WHITE);
     randomapple();
     while(1)
     {
        if(kbhit())
        {
            check=getch();
            switch(check)
            {
            case 'a':if(ch!='d') ch=check;
                break;
            case 'd':if(ch!='a') ch=check;
                break;
            case 'w':if(ch!='s') ch=check;
                break;
            case 's':if(ch!='w') ch=check;
                break;
            case ' ':ch=check;
                break;
            }

        }
        condition();
        shift();
        printsnake();
        collision();
        score();
     }
     }

    }
```

Comment: *Please do not tell me to use new version. And don't call me outdated, I know that.* :) Which operating system?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). I also recommend you to read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), to help you make better code examples to show us. As it is now, you have way to much code, please try to minimize it to the relevant parts only.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please debug your program and try to identify where and how the error occurs. Also, on a side note, use DOSBOX to avoid paging faults.

Comment: Turbo C++ debugging... http://phoenix.goucher.edu/~kelliher/cs17/debugging.html

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the input stream (`kbhit` and `getch`)?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen I dont think it does

Comment: You're outdated.  Use a new version.  And don't put a noose in your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, the problem lies in randomapple function. If you look closer on it, if you set same to 1 then it stays 1 forever. You should reset it every iteration of that while.

Comment: Wow you did it. Thanks . :D